# Span inside div? problems in ie8?

Tags: jquery, html

I have span tag inside div tag.

```
var a = jQuery("<span class = 'B'>");
```

For some reason i am not able to see the contents of var a on ie., but I can see the contenet on mozilla.

Comment: your jquery selector is empty.  what is `a` supposed to be

Answer (score 1):

You have no div there.

Try this one

```
var a = jQuery("<span />", {class:'B'}).appendTo('#yourDiv');
```